# Expo wont recognise AppRoot.tsx when building React-Native App

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I've looked for hours and tried so many solutions trying to get Expo to run a Blank React Native project using Typescript.

I have followed these Two tutorials

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/05/07/using-typescript-with-react-native

and continue to get this
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b1db.png)

I've tried all kinds of solutuions, such as,

- Altering the rn-cli.config.js
- Altering the package.json
- Altering the app.json

none of them have worked and all yield the same error.

Is there a more up to date tutorial i should be following? Or am i just missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of Expo 31.x typescript is natively supported.
If you create a app using Expo or CRNA (both create the same app) then you only have to install typescript and create a App.ts in the root importing src/App.tsx (if u use a src directory structure).

If you already created a app using one of the tutorials you need to remove all the additional files and changes u did regarding typescript (except installined typescript ;) ):

- rn-cli.config.js
- babel-preset-expo
- expo config for typescript (not sure what the filename was)

The tsconfig can be from any of the tutorials, but with:

- targeting ES2017
- noEmit: true